# Set database connection timeout in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, pdo, connection-timeout

We are working with 2 databases, our local database and an external database. But now our external database is down (we're still under development so it's good we came across this issue) and it now tries to connect to the external database for 30 seconds, how can I change the connection timeout of the Database to something like 1 - 2 seconds? I am using Codeigniter with the PDO drivers on my databases. Is there anyone with a clean solution for this problem?

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.connect-timeout

Comment: I'm not using mysql @Scorpion

Comment: Have you tried setting `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT`? What is your database though?

Comment: That's one way to fix the issue, but I don't know if you're using codeigniter, it lets you choose between multiple drivers, (mysql, mysqli and PDO). I would like to know if it's possible to fix this issue without editting to core (which would be the PDO driver as I am using PDO to talk to a Mysql database) @user3584460

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a documented feature, but you can do this from the database config file (`application/config/database.php`) by adding `options` setting e.g.:

```
$db['default']['options'] = array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5);
```

The other settings which use the same internal mechanism (e.g. `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` set with `$db['default']['stricton']` and `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_COMPRESS` set with `$db['default']['compress']`) are not affected by this.

If you want to dig deeper or check which options are set, you can log `$this->options` in `db_connect` function in `system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_driver.php` and also check `database/drivers/pdo/subdrivers/pdo_mysql_driver.php`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, working like a charm! Thanks alot!! I cannot yet give you the bounty but will do so once I can.