# Connection lost during long time process to save records in database sqlite3 codeigniter

Tags: php, database, sqlite, codeigniter, database-connection

I have a heavy process which produce lots of records (>1000000) that should be save to the sqlite3 database in codeigniter.

The setting to connect to database in runtime is like this

```
 $config['hostname'] = '';
    $config['username'] = '';
    $config['password'] = '';
    $config['database'] = './application/database/' . $database_name;
    $config['dbdriver'] = 'sqlite3';
    $config['dbprefix'] = '';
    $config['pconnect'] = false;
    $config['db_debug'] = true;
    $config['autoinit'] = false;
    $config['cache_on'] = false;
    $config['cachedir'] = '';
    $config['stricton'] = false;
    $config['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $config['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $config['save_queries'] = true;
    $config['failover'] = array();
```

my code in CI_Controller is

```
 $counter = 0;
    $this->load->model('db_model');
    for ($j = 0; $j < $MAX_Y; $j++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $MAX_X; $i++) {

            // some process .....
            // prepare $values

            if ($counter > 20000) {
                $this->db_model->insert($values, $config);
                $counter = 0;
                unset($values);
                $values = array();
            } else {
                $counter++;
            }

        }
    }
    if ($counter > 0) {
        $this->db_model->insert($values, $config);
    }
```

my code in db_model is

```
class Db_model extends CI_Model
{
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        set_time_limit(10000);
    }

public function insert($data, $config)
{
    $DB = null;
    $DB = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
    $DB->initialize();
//        $DB->busyTimeout(72000000);
        $DB->trans_start();
        $DB->insert_batch('tbl_name', $data);
        $DB->trans_complete();
        $DB->close();

    }

}
```

During the saving records into table in sqlite3 database suddenly it stop writing the rest of records which is remain and table does not have all records which should have.

I think some thing is wrong with connection time out, and i should change some thing related to connection time out. but i did not find a good answer for this issue after couple of weeks.

Comment: Would you not use insert_batch()?

Comment: @NiallLonergan .  If i use insert() those records which write to table are less than insert_batch()

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this:** `$db['default']['options'] = array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 50000);`
In config file: (`application/config/database.php`)

[Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616461/set-database-connection-timeout-in-codeigniter-3/32673216#32673216)

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused because of your code which is performed before inserting the data, which cause the server connection to break to save the resources.

The best way to do it is just close the connection and reconnect DB manually before the insert query using this:

```
$this->db->close();
$this->db->initialize();
```

Or

```
$this->db->reconnect();
```

Check: [Reconnecting / Keeping the Connection Alive](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#reconnecting-keeping-the-connection-alive) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You put the `set_time_limit(10000);` inside of the model. But you run over a loop in the CI_Controller, and I guess that the inserts them self are not long.

The time out won't happen in the model, it will happen in the controller. So try to change the CI_Controller like this:

```
$counter = 0;
    $this->load->model('db_model');
    set_time_limit(10000); //set time limit to the longest run of this script
    for ($j = 0; $j < $MAX_Y; $j++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $MAX_X; $i++) {

        // some process .....
        // prepare $values

        if ($counter > 20000) {
            $this->db_model->insert($values, $config);
            $counter = 0;
            unset($values);
            $values = array();
        } else {
            $counter++;
        }

    }
}
if ($counter > 0) {
    $this->db_model->insert($values, $config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got super tired of PHP timeouts and I started writing 
"restart-able" programs. The basics...

```
$step=(int)$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

switch($step) {
    case 0:
        /* SETUP */
        redirect($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?1";        
    case 1: 
        /* DO SOME WORK */
        if (work<>done) {
            redirect($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?1"; 
        } else {
            exit;
        }       
}


function redirect($url,$seconds=0) {
    $html="<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='$seconds; URL=$url'></head></html>"; 
    echo $html; 
    exit(); 
}
```